# websocket. how to trigger an onerror event?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I need to test WebSocket on the client:

```js
class NotificationService {
  constructor() {
    this.socket = new WebSocket(`ws:${API_HOST}/ws`);

    this.socket.onerror = this._onError.bind(this);
  }
  
  _onError(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

When an onerror event occurs and how to trigger it?

What do you advise?